Why is it sometimes easier to reason about many dimensions than just three or four?
I'm no mathematician, so I could be totally off base here, so I'm just asking about what I know about.
As I understand it, in the history of solving the Poincaré conjecture, first it was proven true for the case of five dimensions and above, and Perelman's lauded solution was only for the 4-dimensional case.
Reading the story of the Busemann-Petty problem, again I notice that first it was proven false for 12 or more dimensions, then those dimensions were reduced until the four-dimensional case caused the incorrect proof (and is there no proof yet for the three-dimensional case?).
As a layman I can wrap my head around four dimensions on a good day, but anything above that is too complicated for me. But mathematicians seem to have it the other way around: the more dimensions the easier the proof is. I'd just like to know how mathematicians reason so easily in higher dimensions, even if only for the above two cases.

there is more room in higher dimensions.

Working in 1D, 2D, 3D, I think that we try to visualize. For higher dimensions, it is pure abstraction.

Coming from a little philosophical perspective, if you have to few dimensions then there is not much wiggle room for sufficiently good structures/methods to work; wheras if you have too many dimensions then many things kind of unravel easily. Somehow the 3/4 (mainly 4, I am looking at you exotic $\mathbb R^4$) number of dimensions is not too big, not too small, but just right for interesting things to happen.
